# SQL command that spans across tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables (`authors`, `quotes`, `tags`, `quotes_tags`) and I'd like to make a single query for a list of random quotes with their appropriate author and and tags (many) information.

Here's what I have right now, but the tags are being squashed and returning only one. How would I go about query that returns this set of quotes with the tags returned as `json` or whatever convention that's appropriate?

```
SELECT  *
  FROM quotes
  JOIN authors ON quotes.author_id = authors.id
  JOIN tags ON tags.id = quotes.id
  ORDER BY RANDOM()
  LIMIT 50
```

I am getting the following:

```
author | quote | tags
---------------------
john   | lorem | hey
brian  | lorem | test
```

but I'd like the following:

```
author | quote | tags
-------------------------------
john   | lorem | hey, another (or whatever convention for a list -- json?)
brian  | lorem | test, one, two
```

Comment: Can you show us the input data?

Answer (score 0):

In version 8.4 and later, you can use `array_agg`:

```
SELECT a.author, q.quote, array_agg(t.tags)
FROM quotes q
INNER JOIN authors a
    ON q.author_id = a.id
INNER JOIN tags t
    ON t.id = q.id
GROUP BY a.author, q.quote
ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

Comment: And in 9.0 and later you can use `string_agg`

Comment: It should be aggregated by `author_id` and `quote_id`

Comment: Let him message me regarding his actual table structure.